# Adding a UITableView to DetailView of SplitView

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have created a custom UITableView and I want to add it to the DetailView (which is just a UIView). The default UISplitView of Xcode 4 inserts a toolbar in the DetailView. When I add my custom UITableView it overlaps the toolbar.

This is in my DetailViewController, in the "configureView" method that Xcode adds by default:

```
[self.view addSubview:booksFromOpenLibraryController.view];
```

Question 1: is that the best method to add my table view - I'm guessing no, since it then adds the tableView each time a user selects something in the RootView - but where should I place it?

Question 2: How to I avoid having the tableView overlap with the UIToolbar in the UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the TableView once, you can add it in the `viewDidLoad` method.

In the `configureView` method, you can update the tableview's data appropriately to reflect whatever changes are dependent on the root view's selection.

To not have the tableview overlap the toolbar, you need to set the frame and autoresizemask of the tableview appropriately to account for any other views in the detail pane.

Comment: All helpful. However, the table seems to be too short when I play with it's frame. I've added a 44px offset on the top and that works, but it's height doesn't seem to change - I'm using self.view.bounds.size.height (within the UIViewController).